# Why does Google Closure Compiler NOT rename these external variables?

Tags: minify, google-closure-compiler

According to documentation (https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#externs), it seems the closure compiler should rename variables when no external declaration exists, including when using functions/variables from an external bit of code. The example they give is

```
function makeNoteDom(noteTitle, noteContent, noteContainer) {
  // Create DOM structure to represent the note.
  var headerElement = textDiv(noteTitle);
  var contentElement = textDiv(noteContent);
...
}
```

where the textDiv function is declared in the global scope by a third-party lib of some sort. It says textDiv should be declared external to prevent renaming.

My question is - when I put this code or similar into the [Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) without any extern declarations why is textDiv not renamed (which would break the code), as the documentation indicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler assumes that calls to an undefined function are in fact calls to an external functions. Using the command line compiler, you can use `--warning_level VERBOSE` to have the compiler treat this condition as an error.

The [Web Application](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/) is primarily built for demos and assumes this by default. While you can set a `VERBOSE` warning level, it will not change this functionality. See the [Additional Web Service Options](https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/wiki/AdditionalWebserviceOptions) page for information on options. I've filed a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/issues/detail?id=911) about this.

Due to the renaming algorithm for properties, undeclared properties will be renamed in a breaking way if that same property name isn't declared on an object in externs.

Comment: Also: http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/wiki/FAQ#Some_of_my_properties_are_getting_renamed,_but_some_aren't.